# Pyttsx3 worked earlier but not now

Tags: python, pyttsx

In december, 2019, my pyttsx3 module was working fine with no error. After few months I uninstalled Python, But in May 2020 I installed it again. But this time, wierd errors came...
My os is win10Pro , Python 3.7(earier it was the same), IDE is Pycharm. The code is :

```
import pyttsx3


def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


speak("Hello World!")
```

When I run it :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.LP_POINTER(ISpeechRecoGrammar)'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\happy v6\stackoverflow.py", line 10, in <module>
    speak("Hello World!")
  File "E:\happy v6\stackoverflow.py", line 5, in speak
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_C866CA3A_32F7_11D2_9602_00C04F8EE628_0_5_4.py", line 726, in <module>
    ( ['in'], BSTR, 'AdaptationString' )),
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\Romoni Gogoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported
```

I didn't get it. What shoud I do? If you know how to solve it, Please share it with me..

Answer (score 0):

This may help. You should try installing tools for Python. By this I mean the Dev and other dependecies. One way to install python Dev tools is `apt-get install python-dev` if this didn't work, you will do this same thing but with the python version.

Comment: I think there was some problem with the updated version of pyaudio, so I used `python -m pip install pyttsx3==2.71` and fetched the earlier version of pyttsx3, luckily it worked! ;-)